# Looping through a nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
hash = {key1: "value1", key2: {key3: "value2", key4: "value3"}}
```

My goal is to access the values of `key3` and `key4`.

My code is:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.each do |k, v|
    puts k
    puts v
  end
end
```

I get an output with error:

```
key1
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "value1":String
```

Can someone explain what is going on, and why I am getting this error?

Comment: A bit of advice for the future: post clean, properly formatted code. That noise from IRB is useless (in fact, it distracts very much from reading the code)

Comment: What's the logic behind that structure? Do you need to filter all keys that have a hash value first, because it seems that you can't simply access `hash[:key2].values`?

Comment: @Ja͢ck: do you mean "you can simply access"? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes (because in this example that would be the obvious approach), and no (because it's probably meant to be more dynamic) :)

Comment: Thanks guys! So much to learn still! :)

Comment: Ow wow, my whole question got rewritten... I fully get the purpose of clean, properly formatted code but I also want to add a remark: 
I often feel like there is information missing that experienced programmers perhaps take for granted. As a beginner I often get confused to where code should go. I've found that the noise sometimes acts as hints to tell me where it supposed to go. Just my 2 cents not to go overboard with cleaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{key1: "value1", key2: {key3: "value2", key4: "value3"}}
```

Your hash is not consistent hash of hashes, in the first iteration, `value` is `value1` which is a string, and you cannot iterate over a `string`.

to avoid that, you can check beforehand like,

```
hash.each do |key,value|
  p key
  if value.is_a?(Hash)
    value.each do |k,v|
      p k
      p v
    end
  else
    p value
  end
end
```

> My goal is to access the values of key3 and key4. (I want to put them in a variable of some kind to be used elsewhere)

you can traverse a hash based on key associations. As per your need above, you can simply do:

```
hash[:key2][:key3]
#=> "value2"
hash[:key2][:key4]
#=> "value3"
```

Comment: ...or `val3, val4 = hash[:key2].values_at(:key3, :key4)`